# HTML5 Autocapitalize not working for input type = text

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I'm building a hybrid mobile app and on the login screen I want to make the username input to open the keyboard without the autocapitalize being set.
I used the HTML5 autocapitalize attribute set to "none" (also tried the value "off") but the property is being ignored both on Android and iOS when the input type is text:

https://www.screencast.com/t/EHPjByuurZjQ

The following code shows the html being used:

```html
<input type="text" data-input="" class="form-control" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" id="Input_UsernameVal">
```

Can anyone help me with this? Is there another way to force the keyboard to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The autocapitalize attribute will not make all letters become uppercase or lowercase. For doing that you can use JavaScript or CSS (for display purposes only).

It will only **change the behavior of the keyboard on mobile devices**. In other words, the way that the keyboard will be displayed when the user opens the keyboard on a input text or textarea field.

To see it in action, [click here](https://live.browserstack.com/dashboard#os=android&os_version=8.0&device=Samsung+Galaxy+S9+Plus&device_browser=chrome&zoom_to_fit=true&full_screen=true&url=www.google.com&speed=1) and then copy and paste the following link in the browser:
https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/autocapitalize/

When you click on each field you will see the behavior of the keyboard.

### For reference

```
<tag autocapitalize="off | none | on | sentences | words | characters" />
```

#### Possible values

| Value | Description |
| --- | --- |
| off | none | Text will not be capitalized. |
| on | sentences | The first letter of each sentence will be capitalized. |
| words | The first letter of each word will be capitalized. |
| characters | The entire text will be capitalized. |

The autocapitalize attribute never causes autocapitalization to be enabled for an  element with a type attribute whose value is url, email, or password.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this](https://caniuse.com/#search=autoc) to validate the compatibility else try by using only css using `text-transform` property

```
.Input_UsernameVal{
   text-transform:lowercase
}
```

Comment: Hi. That will format the text inside the input to lowercase but the keyboard that is opened still has the capitalized value by default. My goal is to make it working as it works for instance if autocapitalize="none" and type="email", since for this input type the HTML5 attribute works as I need (but I need type="text")